# convert unicode to char

Tags: c++, unicode, char, locale, c++builder

How can I convert a Unicode string to a `char*` or `char* const` in [embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/) c++ ?

Comment: From Unicode to what locale? Or if on windows which codepage? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/ ?

Comment: Embarcadero seems [remarkably well documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/TEncoding_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: I'm sorry but you clearly didn't actually search the documentation, I found [__the exact page that addresses this issue__](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UnicodeString.t_str) in under 60 seconds. As another stated, Embarcadero does an impeccable job of providing robust documentation with relevant examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unicode string" really isn't specific enough to know what your source data is, but you probably mean 'UTF-16 string stored as wchar_t array' since that's what most people who don't know the correct terminology use.

"char*" also isn't enough to know what you want to target, although maybe "embarcadero" has some convention. I'll just assume you want UTF-8 data unless you mention otherwise.

Also I'll limit my example to what works in VS2010

```
// your "Unicode" string
wchar_t const * utf16_string = L"Hello, World!";

// #include <codecvt>
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;

std::string utf8_string = convert.to_bytes(utf16_string);
```

This assumes that wchar_t strings are UTF-16, as is the case on Windows, but otherwise is portable code.

Comment: Embarcadero does indeed have "some convention" as you put it. Quote from docs: *'Delphi also supports UnicodeString, but implements it as a primitive type rather than a class. By default, variables declared as type String are UnicodeString.'* Also important to note: *'Despite its name, UnicodeString can represent both Unicode strings and ANSI strings, ANSI strings being converted first.'*

Comment: 'ANSI string' is still insufficient even if we ignore the fact that the American National Standards Institute has never defined such a thing and recognize that thay are referring to what Microsoft refers to by that name; Microsoft defines many 'code pages' which can be used with so-called "ANSI" strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
String text = "Hello world";
char *txt = AnsiString(text).c_str();
```

Comment: This is the proper answer, straight from the Embarcadero documentation.

Comment: This will fail to handle any characters outside the locale being used, and since there is no locale on Windows that supports all characters (e.g., a UTF-8 locale would support all characters) `AnsiString` simply cannot provide lossless conversions for all inputs on Windows.

Comment: Note that you can specify the codepage for an AnsiString: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_AnsiString_Code_Page_Specification_in_C%2B%2B However, you are right that converting from Unicode to ANSI may (and often will) be lossy.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinterpret any array as an array of char pointers legally. So if your Unicode data comes in 4-byte code units like

```
char32_t data[100];
```

then you can access it as a char array:

```
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const*>(data);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof data; ++i)
{
    std::printf("Byte %03zu is 0x%02X.\n", i, p[i]);
}
```

That way, you can examine the individual bytes of your Unicode data one by one.

(That has of course nothing to do with *converting the encoding* of your text. For that, use a library like `iconv` or ICU.)

Comment: Sine the OP specifically asked to convert, this doesn't seem a very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Windows:

```
//#include <windows.h>
u16string utext = u"объява";
char text[0x100];
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8,NULL,(const wchar_t*)(utext.c_str()),-1,text,-1,NULL,NULL);
cout << text;
```

We can't use std::wstring_convert, wherefore  is not available in MinGW 4.9.2.