# Encode/Decode std::string to UTF-16

Tags: c++, utf-16, stdstring

I have to handle a file format (both read from and write to it) in which strings are encoded in UTF-16 (2 bytes per character). Since characters out of the ASCII table are rarely used in the application  domain, all of the strings in my C++ model classes are stored in instances of std::string (UTF-8 encoded).

I'm looking for a library (searched in STL and Boost with no luck) or a set of C/C++ functions to handle this std::string <-> UTF-16 conversion when loading from or saving to file format (actually modeled as a bytestream) including the generation/recognition of surrogate pairs and all that Unicode stuffs (I'm admittedly no expert with)...

Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: forgot to mention it should be cross-platform (Win / Mac) and cannot use C++11.

Comment: Ah, I looked into ICU but it seems too over-sized for my task.

Comment: If you are _only_ targeting windows, use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx), in all other cases, use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).  It _can_ be done yourself, but shouldn't be.

Comment: This has been asked plenty of times, the one I'm most familiar with is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl

Comment: Oh hey, [boost has unicode iterators!](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0_beta1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/internal_details/uni_iter.html)

Answer (score 19):

C++11 has this functionality:

```
std::string s = u8"Hello, World!";

// #include <codecvt>
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<char16_t,char,std::mbstate_t>,char16_t> convert;

std::u16string u16 = convert.from_bytes(s);
std::string u8 = convert.to_bytes(u16);
```

However to my knowledge the only implementation that has this so far is libc++. C++11 also has `std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>` which some other implementations have. Specifically, `codecvt_utf8_utf16` works in VS 2010 and above, and since wchar_t is used by Windows to represent UTF-16 you can use this to [convert between UTF-8 and Windows' native encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040983/365496).

---

> The specialization `codecvt<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>` converts between the UTF-16 and UTF-8 encoding
>   schemes, and the specialization `codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>` converts between the UTF-32 and
>   UTF-8 encoding schemes.
>
> *— [locale.codecvt] 22.4.1.4/3*

---

Oh, and std::codecvt specializations have protected destructors, and wstring_convert requires access to the destructor so you really need an adapter:

```
template <class Facet>
class usable_facet : public Facet {
public:
    using Facet::Facet; // inherit constructors
    ~usable_facet() {}

    // workaround for compilers without inheriting constructors:
    // template <class ...Args> usable_facet(Args&& ...args) : Facet(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};

template<typename internT, typename externT, typename stateT> 
using codecvt = usable_facet<std::codecvt<internT, externT, stateT>>;

std::wstring_convert<codecvt<char16_t,char,std::mbstate_t>> convert;
```

Comment: Whoa, what!? +1 I've never seen this :)

Comment: Hmm, made a test case to test extended plane characters, but IDEOne won't compile it: http://ideone.com/UdZcL

Comment: @MooingDuck unfortunately libstdc++ still hasn't implemented these specializations, even as of gcc 4.7.

Comment: How do you manage utf-16 BE or utf-16 LE and are able to switch between them (while writing to file)?

Comment: @Sandburg One of the template parameters of the UTF codecvt facets is a codecvt_mode that allows you to specify options like endianness and BOMs. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html)?  [This page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html), in particular, describes how to do UTF to UTF conversions and how to integrate it with IOStreams.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look at:

[Convert C++ std::string to UTF-16-LE encoded string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703630/convert-c-stdstring-to-utf-16-le-encoded-string)

And check out the iconv function.  It's a C library, no requirements for C++11.

There's also a Win32 specific iconv library at https://github.com/win-iconv/win-iconv.