# Is this code Endian safe?

Tags: c++, endianness

I am testing following peace of code for possible Endian issue. Code was written for ppc and needs to be run on x86 box now.

```
string Mac = nodeMessage->getMac();
char mac_string[17];
strncpy(mac_string, Mac.c_str(),16);
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Endian-ness of a machine affects integral values that are more than one byte wide. I don't see any integral values there. Hence, I don't see any Endian-ness problems associated with the above code.

Comment: I see 17 integers, but agreed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing only with 1 byte chars(ASCII) then its Endian safe else its not.

the following link may be helpful.

[Encode/Decode std::string to UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086183/encode-decode-stdstring-to-utf-16)

Answer (score 0):

Completing the answer of R Sahu, the problem could be the `nodeMessage` and how it manages the mac (I suppose that it refers to a mac address).