# How can I convert string with local encoding to UTF-16 wide string in C++?

Tags: c++, encoding, std, wstring

I have a `std::string` with a known encoding, e.g. GB-18030. Is there a way to pass the string with the name of encoding to some functionality which converts the string to a UTF-16 wide string?

I don't see a way how to do it with `std::wstring_convert`.

Comment: The UTF16 string type is `u16string`, not `wstring`. The function that converts between string types is [codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode/Decode std::string to UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086183/encode-decode-stdstring-to-utf-16)

Comment: Besides, [GB-18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030) already is a multi-byte encoding.